# Using salmon in 2 days, freezer or fridge?

Tags: fish, storage, salmon

I have a fresh cut of salmon I plan to cook for dinner in two days. I know that fish is best cooked as soon and as fresh as possible or should go right into the freezer.

Which is the best storage method? Should I put it in the freezer for just one day, and then take it out tomorrow to thaw overnight? Or should I leave for two days in the fridge?

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Temperature works on a scale, the cooler it is, usually the less active bacteria will be.

With this in mind, my fridge has a special zone for meats and fish, very very close to zero degrees. The food won't freeze, but bacterial activity will be slowed enough that I would put it there a couple of days without worrying.

Freezing goes way beyond zero, usually - 13 to - 21 in some fridges, but it changes the quality of the product, specially if not vacuum sealed.

If your fridge has a special zone for meats like mine, I would use it. If not, freeze it just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Did you buy it from the grocery store? Most salmon have been flash frozen to rid of parasites. If that's the case, I would just leave it in the fridge if you're planning to cook it in 2 days. If you were to freeze it, the freeze-thaw process could affect the texture of the salmon.